# Push notification for uploading new video in Youtube in Android app

Tags: android, youtube, push-notification, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have integrated YouTube API with my Android app. I am able to fetch all kind of information from API and display it into my app. Currently, I am looking for the solution to show push notification in Android app whenever I uploaded video on youtube.

Is there any API available for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a server side to do this,
- you can to develop a cron job to run with interval Like 10 minutes
- get channel videos based on publishing time

```
  $minutes= round(abs(time() - strtotime( $video['published'])) / 10,0);
```

if minutes less than 10 minutes you can get this video details and push it to your app

I have sample code written in php from 4 years ago

```
$youtubelib= APPPATH.'include/youtube.php';
include_once($youtubelib);
$channels=$this->channels->getChannelsPush();
foreach ($channels as $key => $value) {
$channel[$key]= new youtube();
$channel[$key]->set_username($value);
$feed[$key]=$channel[$key]->feed();
$vedios[$key]=$feed[$key]['videos'];

foreach ($vedios as $key => $value) {
               foreach ($value as $key => $value2) {
                                $minutes=   round(abs(time() - strtotime($value2['published'])) / 60,0);
                                             // <= 60 last hour    edit it for production
                                          if($minutes <=60)
                                                {
                                                $value2['different_time']=$minutes;
                                                $test[]=$value2;
                                                 }
                                                     }
                                }
echo "No videos published on last hour to push </br>"; 
if(!empty($test))
{
echo "vedios has been pushed </br>";
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
echo "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$value['id'];
$t=$this->apipush->addtrack($value['title'],$value['id'],1);
exec($this->androidvedioPush($value['title'],$value['id'],$value['cover'][0],$t));
 }
```

- as well you can use firebase (FCM) and use topic feature to push it on realtime
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) on how YouTube Data API (v3) supports push notifications via [PubSubHubbub](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/).

> Notifications are pushed out to subscribers via HTTP webhooks, which is much more efficient than polling-based solutions. With PubSubHubbub, your server finds out about events in near real-time, without having to determine the optimal polling interval or repeatedly fetching data that hasn’t changed.
>
> Your PubSubHubbub callback server receives Atom feed notifications when a channel does any of the following activities:
>
> - uploads a video
> - updates a video's title
> - updates a video's description

You can find the steps that explains how to subscribe to notifications in the documentation above.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But I don't think this api is work for android. Please correct me if I am wrong.